# How to read .txt file using split and Array

Tags: java

My question would be how to use .split to read .txt file like this:

```
SG75J6: Dark Brown 2200 x 75 x 24.5 12.3
NG6083: Grey Window 2500 x 63.5 x 17.2 13.4
NG6083: Red 2500 x 63.5 x 17.2 13.4
```

My code:

```
Scanner s = null;
        String line = null;
            s = new Scanner(new File("/Users/kompiuteris/Desktop/pvzkontras.txt"));
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                line = s.nextLine();

                String[] duom = line.split(":");


                String gamintojas = duom[0];

                duom = line.split(" ");

                String pavadinimas = duom[1];

                double ilgis = Double.parseDouble(duom[2].trim());

                duom = line.split(" x ");

                double plotis = Double.parseDouble(duom[3].trim());

                double aukstis = Double.parseDouble(duom[4].trim());

                duom = line.split(" ");

                double kaina = Double.parseDouble(duom[5].trim());

                System.out.println(gamintojas + " " + pavadinimas + " " + ilgis + " " + plotis + " " + aukstis + " " + kaina);
```

Error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3`

Any suggestions? Also, how to detect this part `Dark Brown 2200` when there's two words or even more and I need to find out if the next symbol is number?

Comment: You do this with regular expressions. Have a look at this https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick regex for parsing such lines. Note I've made some assumptions regarding the valid characters for each part, so some tweaking could be needed.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = ("SG75J6: Dark Brown 2200 x 75 x 24.5 12.3\n"
                    + "NG6083: Grey Window 2500 x 63.5 x 17.2 13.4\n"
                    + "NG6083: Red 2500 x 63.5 x 17.2 13.4");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z\\d]+): ([A-Za-z ]+) ([\\d.]+) x ([\\d.]+) x ([\\d.]+) ([\\d.]+)");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SG75J6
Dark Brown
2200
75
24.5
12.3
NG6083
Grey Window
2500
63.5
17.2
13.4
NG6083
Red
2500
63.5
17.2
13.4
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you can do this utilizing [Regular Expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx). Here is an example of carrying out this task using different Regular Expressions along with the [String#split()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-split) and the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) methods:

```
//String line = "SG75J6: Dark Brown 2200 x 75 x 24.5 12.3";
String line = "NG6083: Grey Window 2500 x 63.5 x 17.2 13.4";
//String line = "NG6083: Red 2500 x 63.5 x 17.2 13.4";
    
String[] duom = line.split("\\s{0,}:\\s{0,}");
String gamintojas = duom[0];
    
String pavadinimas = duom[1].split("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")[0].trim();
    
String numericals = duom[1].replaceAll("[a-z A-Z]{1,}"," ").trim();
String[] numericalArray = numericals.split("\\s+");
try {
    double ilgis = Double.parseDouble(numericalArray[0]);
    double plotis = Double.parseDouble(numericalArray[1]);
    double aukstis = Double.parseDouble(numericalArray[2]);
    double kaina = Double.parseDouble(numericalArray[3]);
    
    // Display the results...
    System.out.println("gamintojas equals:  " + gamintojas);
    System.out.println("pavadinimas equals: " + pavadinimas);
    System.out.println("ilgis equals:       " + ilgis);
    System.out.println("plotis equals:      " + plotis);
    System.out.println("aukstis equals:     " + aukstis);
    System.out.println("kaina equals:       " + kaina);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Do whatever you want here!
    System.out.println("Whoops! A Double.parseDouble() Error!");
}
```

**What do the Regular Expressions mean:**

> **String[] duom = line.split("\\s{0,}:\\s{0,}");**
>
> **String gamintojas = duom[0];**

Split the string in **line** based on any Colon (**:**) found within the string ***even if*** it has one or more white-spaces ***before OR after*** the colon. The **duom** Array variable now contains 2 elements:

```
At Element 0: "NG6083"
At Element 1: "Grey Window 2500 x 63.5 x 17.2 13.4"
```

We now take the first element (**duom[0]**) and place it into the **gamintojas** variable.

> **String pavadinimas = duom[1].split("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")[0].trim()**

Split the string contained within the 2nd element of the **duom** Array variable (duom[1]) based on string representations of signed or unsigned Integer or Double numerical values but accept only the first element ([0]) of that split and trim any possible white-spaces from it. The pavadinimas variable now contains:

```
"Grey Window"
```

> **String numericals = duom[1].replaceAll("[a-z A-Z]{1,}"," ").trim();**

Create a String (**numericals**) to hold all the numerical values contained within the 2nd element of the **duom** Array variable (duom[1]) as white-space delimited string using the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) method. The RegEx used in the **replaceAll()** method will replace all characters (1 or more) which are 'a' to 'z' or 'A' to 'Z' or white-spaces and replace them with a single white-space (" "). The replacement is then trimmed of leading and trailing white-spaces right away. The **numericals** string variable will now contain:

```
"2500 63.5 17.2 13.4"
```

> **String[] numericalArray = numericals.split("\\s+");**

This line creates a String Array named **numericalArray** by splitting the newly created **numericals** variable based on **one or more** (should there for some reason be more) white-spaces. The elements contained within the **numericalArray** String Array will look like:

```
At Element 0: "2500"
At Element 1: "63.5"
At Element 2: "17.2"
At Element 3: "13.4"
```

Now it's just a matter of parsing each element of the **numericalArray** array into its respective ***double type*** variables using the [Double.parseDouble()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_parsedouble.htm) method and then displaying the results.

The parsing is housed within a [try/catch](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp) block just in case a ***NumberFormatException*** is thrown for some reason.